# nginx reverse proxy with backend redirect

Tags: nginx

This should be a common issue but I can't seem to find the right configuration, say I want

domain/foo -> domain:80

The following works:

```
location /foo/ {
  proxy_pass         http://domain:80/;
  proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
```

But if domain:80 itself redirects to something like domain/bar
Then I try this:

```
location /foo/ {
  proxy_pass         http://domain:80/bar/;
  proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
```

But then for anything under http://domain:80/bar/obj1, I get a 404 error.

Also can nginx detect the backend redirect so I don't have to hardcode "bar/" in proxy_pass?

Comment: Why do you specify port 80? It is the default, and it looks like your server is proxy passing to itself. Would a `rewrite` be more appropriate? See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

Comment: I specify 80 because it is under 443; I am doing reverse proxying for SSL.

So location is under:

    `server {
          listen 443 ssl default_server;`